# 3D Tikz in Cylindrical Polar Co-ordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I am trying to construct the image below in Tikz. Aside from calculating each Cartesian co-ordinate by hand and then inputting them, I'd like to use cylindrical polar co-ordinates seeing as it would be much quicker.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (1) at (0,0,0) {$\mathbb{Q}$};
        \node (11) at (0,-1,0) {$\mathbb{Z}$};
    \node (2) at (1.732,0,-1) {$\mathbb{Q}_{2}$};
        \node (21) at (1.732,-1,-1) {$\mathbb{Z}_{2}$};
        \node (22) at (3.464,0,-2) {$\mathbb{C}_{2}$};
    \node (3) at (1.732,0,1) {$\mathbb{Q}_{3}$};
        \node (31) at (1.732,-1,1) {$\mathbb{Z}_{3}$};
        \node (32) at (3.464,0,2) {$\mathbb{C}_{3}$};
    \node (5) at (0,0,2) {$\mathbb{Q}_{5}$};
        \node (51) at (0,-1,2) {$\mathbb{Z}_{5}$};
        \node (52) at (0,0,4) {$\mathbb{C}_{5}$};
    \node (7) at (-1.732,0,1) {$\mathbb{Q}_{7}$};
        \node (71) at (-1.732,-1,1) {$\mathbb{Z}_{7}$};
        \node (72) at (-3.464,0,2) {$\mathbb{C}_{7}$};
    \node (11) at (-1.732,0,-1) {$\mathbb{Q}_{11}$};
        \node (111) at (-1.732,-1,-1) {$\mathbb{Z}_{11}$};
        \node (112) at (-3.464,0,-2) {$\mathbb{C}_{11}$};
    \node (10) at (0,0,-2) {$\mathbb{R}$};
        \node (101) at (0,0,-4) {$\mathbb{C}$};

    \draw (1) to (11);
    \draw[->] (1) to (2);
    \draw[->] (1) to (3);
    \draw[->] (1) to (5);
    \draw[->] (1) to (7);
    \draw[->] (1) to (11);
    \draw[->] (1) to (10);

    \draw (2) to (21);
    \draw[->] (2) to (22);
    \draw (3) to (31);
    \draw[->] (3) to (32);
    \draw (5) to (51);
    \draw[->] (5) to (52);
    \draw (7) to (71);
    \draw[->] (7) to (72);
    \draw (11) to (111);
    \draw[->] (11) to (112);

    \draw[->] (10) to (101);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The **Q** should be in the centre of the circle with **R** above it in the *xy*-plane (although tikz seems to orientate it strangely) with **Q2**, **Q3** etc going round in a circle in the *xy*-plane an being evenly spaced. Then I want the **Z**s spread directly underneath their corresponding **Q**s. Finally, I want the **C**s to be 1 unit further away from the central **Q** than their corresponding **Q**s.

I am happy to reduce the number of `spokes' to make the picture neater but would like at least 5.

Comment: I have uploaded the code I have used, along with the image it creates (I have colour arrows but that's not important).

Comment: Perhaps the `\tdplotsetcoord` macro from the `tikz-3dplot` package can be helpful here.

Comment: To define cyclindrical polar co-ordinates? I haven't used it the macro before but I'll give it a go.

Comment: Oops, sorry, my brain interpreted polar as spherical.

Comment: To be fair, I should have stated beforehand. You weren't really wrong to assume spherical polar as I think they're the more common. I shall be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cylindrical coordinate system does exist.

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
    \tikz{
        \draw[->](0,0)--(1,0)node[right]{$x$};
        \draw[->](0,0)--(0,1)node[above]{$y$};
        \draw[->](0,0)--(0,0,1)node[below left]{$z$};
        \fill foreach\i in{1,...,100}{
            (xyz cylindrical cs:angle=\i0,radius=1,z=\i/10)circle(.1)
        };
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Edit

I hope this will give you some ideal on usage of `\foreach`

```
\tikz[x={(-.8cm,-.6cm)},y={(1cm,0cm)},z={(0cm,1cm)}]{
    \draw[->](0,0)--(1,0)node[below left]{$x$};
    \draw[->](0,0)--(0,1)node[right]{$y$};
    \draw[->](0,0)--(0,0,1)node[above]{$z$};
    \foreach\p[count=\i]in{2,3,5,7,9,\infty}{
        \draw
            (xyz cylindrical cs:angle=\i*60,radius=0,z=4)--
            (xyz cylindrical cs:angle=\i*60,radius=2,z=4)node{$Q_\p$}--
            (xyz cylindrical cs:angle=\i*60,radius=2,z=2)node{$Z_\p$}
            (xyz cylindrical cs:angle=\i*60,radius=2,z=4)--
            (xyz cylindrical cs:angle=\i*60,radius=4,z=4)node{$C_\p$};
    };
}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks good. Do you know how I should implement this for my image? I'm not well-versed in using `for` loops in Tikz.

Comment: Very nice, especially the use of p.