# Plotting 2D functions in 3D space

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have two 2D functions. I want to plot these functions about the z-axis, i.e. they are rotating about the z-axis, such that their different orientations are specified. That is, I don't want a 3D appearance - 5 or 6 fixed angle rotations within 90 degrees would be sufficient.

I have looked at the archive of questions available in the TeX.SE but cannot find anything that doesn't include specifying surfaces, etc.

Comment: Use cylindrical coordinate system. For example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361971/51022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is a good start.

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}

\tikz[x={(-.6cm,-.48cm)},y={(.8cm,-.36cm)},z={(0cm,.8cm)}]{
    \draw[->](5,0,0)node{$x$}(-3,0,0)--(4,0,0);
    \draw[->](0,5,0)node{$y$}(0,-3,0)--(0,4,0);
    \draw[->](0,0,5)node{$z$}(0,0,-3)--(0,0,4);
    \foreach\t in{5,10,...,100}{
        \draw[red!\t!blue]plot(xyz cylindrical cs:angle=3.6*\t,radius=3-\x*\x/10,z={1+\x*(\x+3)*(\x-3)/50});}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had developed a bit of code since your suggestion regarding employing cylindrical coordinates. I presume "xyz cylindrical cs" defines the translation between cartesian and cylindrical coordinates? Another question, if, in cartesian coordinates, the coordinate y depends on x (obviously), then in order to simply rotate a function such as y=1/x around the z-axis, you would set z=y and r (or \rho) =x with the angle \phi defining the rotation in the cylindrical coordinate system?

Comment: @stars83clouds That is the correct setting!